# Jackson: Get non-decoded JSON string value from JSON with dynamic structure (JsonObject)

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I'm using a JSON file to specify a template for the request body for HTTP requests to a backend. I'm inserting parameter values into the request body through a custom placeholder syntax:

```
{
    "requestBody": {
        "desc": "{descriptionParameter}"
    }
}
```

The placeholder logic looks for `{placeholder}` patterns in the JSON strings, and replaces them with the respective parameter values.

Now, I also want to have the possibility to specify a request body with literal curly braces, so my idea was to not do any replacement if the curly braces are quoted in the JSON:

```
{
    "requestBody": {
        "desc": "\u007BnonReplacedLiteral\u007D"
    }
}
```

However I could not find a way to get hold of the non-decoded JSON string. Is this possible with Jackson?

---

Here is the code that I'm currently using: I use a Jackson `ObjectMapper` to parse the JSON into the following object:

```java
public class RequestTemplate {
    ObjectNode requestBody;

    // ... getters
}
```

The `requestBody` object doesn't have a fixed structure, so I can only map it to an `ObjectNode` and then need to use the tree API from that point on:

```java
Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> propertyIterator = requestBody.fields();
while (propertyIterator.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, JsonNode> property = propertyIterator.next();
    String string = property.getValue().textValue();

    // string is now the decoded value - how would I get the non-decoded value?

    // ... parameter replacement logic
}
```

Comment: That seems fragile as you might not be able to actually know whether and where such an encoding or decoding might happen. I'd suggest you use some other form of escaping literals, like `\{literal\}` or `{{literal}}` etc. - or, if you still can change it, use something to mark placeholders that's very likely never used for literals such as `${placeholder}` or `@{placeholder}`.